# how can I do impex clean-up in sap hybris 2105 version? I have storefront Spartacus

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

how can I do Impex clean-up in sap hybris 2105 version?

I have storefront Spartacus . need to solve below error :

```
  [java] ERROR [main] [DefaultSetupImpexService] Importing [cms-content-pdp.impex]... FAILED
```

Comment: check logs from backoffice against cronjob id.

Comment: @RaushanKumar- I run ant initialize and got failed error in my logs . Need to resolve that. what steps need to follow to clean that.

Comment: try to run impex again via hac to see the actual error and fix it.